# WooCommerce Select Products Who's Attribute Value != null

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using custom woocommerce.php & the whole set of woocommerce template files inside my theme.

If I say pass a query string say: `mysite.com/shop/?searchtype=1`

How do I fetch only those products whose color `(custom attribute) == null ?` & also `vice-versa != (not null)`?

Comment: it's hard to create a cross-website out of the box solution for what you want but a script can be made, we'll have to know the taxonomy_id and the term_id for your color attribute, also if we would know the terms ids might help([red, yellow, green]'s terms and taxonomy ids)

Comment: You should show the code of one of your templates. And what you're trying to do, even if it doesn't work. See [ask] and [sscce.org](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Here's the non working code: It works but the != operator is of no use. Maybe some help in understanding :)

 <?php
       $args = array(
        'meta_compare' => '!=',
        'pa_color' => 'f'
       );
       $wp_query = new WP_Query($args);
  ?>